# JavaScript - shorten math function

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function randomize() {
var ra = Math.floor(Math.random()*ar.length=4);
document.getElementById('es').innerHTML = ar[ra];
}
```

Is there a way to short this code even more than it is? The reason why is because I'm going to be using  this code a lot in other projects and objects and I cannot just call it inside like this: randomize(); because I have diffrent arrays.

Comment: What is this piece of code: `ar.length=4`?

Comment: Did you mean to do that =4  ?  I think that should cause a parsing error.

Comment: @pimvdb: could you explain what it does? I look at it and have no idea what it does, or how it works (or, indeed, *if* it works).

Comment: @David Thomas: I'm sorry, I overlooked the `*`. This is indeed a parse error.

Comment: Oh thank you for pointing out that number in the code. That was a spelling mistake. I found the answer in one of the answers bellow.

Comment: Firefox gives me a "Invalid assignment left-hand side"

Comment: @Tremmors No shit, Sherlock! The problem is that I had a typo.

Comment: @user1431627, that is what I said originally.  My more recent comment was directed at a (now edited) comment that said it wouldn't give an error.

Comment: I do see what's happening! Btw, do you have any idea on how to make my JavaScript code, generally, look more like C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function randomize() {document.getElementById('es').innerHTML = ar[Math.floor(Math.random()*ar.length)];}
```

But you wanted to use it more without a function call:

```
function $(id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
}

function randomize() {
$('es').innerHTML = ar[Math.floor(Math.random()*ar.length)];
}
```

And instead of `Math.floor`, you can use `~~` for a microscopical faster diffrence.

This saves some space and time if you are going to use it more. But if only one time, use the first example.

Comment: Thank you. I was unsure about the whole thing and how to shorten it. But how do I specify the arrays length withouth length?.. . like numbers.

Comment: If I understand correct: Instead of ar.length > ar[integer value here]

Comment: I am adding this to accepted answer because it seems lighter, faster and better than the one with 1 upvote. How do you make this code look more like C++?

Comment: What do you mean? C++ and JavaScript is very diffrent.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what, precisely, you're doing, I'd suggest passing the relevant arguments into the function as parameters:

```
function randomize(el, array){
    if (!el || !array){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var ra = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length=4);
        // please note that I don't understand what's happening in the above line
        // and suspect, quite strongly, that the '=4' was a typo. Correct as necessary
        el.innerHTML = ar[ra];
    }
}

// call:
randomize(document.getElementById('es'), ['1','2']);
/* or:
var el = document.getElementById('es'),
    array = ['one','two'];
randomize(el,array);
```

Comment: Figured it out and I saw what I did wrong. What is bad with the other guys' code, btw? I am confused.

Comment: Well, I am of course biased...but you'd have to evaluate which piece of code best suits your needs. Try them, and see which works best to fit your use-case and circumstances.

Comment: Dose the CPU get less load of less code and less to go through?

Comment: But why do I need an if statement?

Comment: The `if` is used to prevent errors in the case of the function being called without the required arguments/parameters.

Comment: I am calling this in a button and that may give bigger problems? Aha. This is just like C++. Way cooler than I thought JavaScript would be. It uses underscores and returns values. And, we can even set this on benchmark to test it in speed!